# msiexec error - GetPriveteProfileStringW

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

I just finished a fresh install of Windows 7 Ultimate and I keep getting the same error every time I try to install any msi file. From what I can tell, the software still installs as far as I can tell. The error message is as follows:

The procedure entry point GetPriveteProfileStringW could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.

When I looked around the internet, I didn't really get anything that made a lot of sence. Does anyone have any thoughts? I'm at a loss at where to go from here.

Comment: It the typo ("e" rather than "a") in `GetPrivateProfileStringW` yours, or is this the exact message?

Comment: Nope, not a typo. That is exactly what I get in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that something was messed up with my windows 7 install. I wiped the machine and reinstalled. It seems to be working much better now.

Answer (score 0):

The application is misinterpreting the operating system version and is trying to call a procedure in the Windows XP version of the Dynamic Link Library (DLL) that is unavailable in Windows 7

Just try and find software which is compatible with windows 7

Comment: Could it be the installer (that handles MSI files) itself that is broken...? Could hardly be the case with a fresh install of Windows 7 but still, apparently *any* MSI file yields this error? Maybe the "e" in "Privete" is not a typo...?

Comment: Is it a typo? if it isnt then i have never heard of this error

Comment: If the MSI installer is busted, how whould you fix something like that?